# How do I use variables from a table?

Tags: matlab

I was wondering how can I call a variable within a table that I have created?

For instance, lets say I have a table with these variables:

Width
3
4.5
5
6.7

Length
4.6
5.7
5.7
5.6

Type
1
1
3
4

How do I ask Matlab to retrieve all numbers that are equal to 1 from Type variable?
Here's what I am trying to do:

```
A=[]; %Create empty matrix
for i=1:numel(Type) %for every number within the variable
  if Type(i) == '1'; %if it equals to 1
      A(i)= Type(1) %append to matrix
  end
end
```

Comment: Please describe how your input data looks like (really of datatype table? Your description sounds more like three arrays?) and what output do you expect for that data.

Comment: This was example data, but I have a data set with 210 rows and 8 columns. They are separated by area, perimeter, length of claw etc. What I am trying to do, is grab a certain part of the data. Basically one column has 1= this species, 2= this species etc. I only want "1"s.

Comment: There is no need for an example actually representing the dimensions of your problem, but without knowing what data structure you got it is difficult to answer. Three arrays of double or a table?

Comment: I apologize for the confusion, this is a table 210x8 and it contains 210 individual animals and the columns identify their measurements (7) with the last column identifying species by 1=crab etc. The output I am wanting is the species with the 1 in the last column.

Comment: @nefa - you should edit your question to include the details that you've put in the above comments.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing

Answer (score 2):

You need use what's called "[logical Indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/find-array-elements-that-meet-a-condition.html?searchHighlight=%22logical%20indexing%22)" - 
Let's say you have a variable `tbl`:

```
>>tbl= [110 1; 120 2; 13  3;140 1]

tbl =

   110     1
   120     2
    13     3
   140     1
```

We want to get all entries where the second column is == 1.  We can create a similar sized array, where there is an entry for each row of `tbl`, where it's `false` if ~=1, or `true` if it's ==:

```
>>index = tbl(:, 2)==1

index =

     1
     0
     0
     1
```

Note the use of the `:` operator - that says "use all elements" - in this case, all rows.  Now, you just apply that to tbl itself:

```
>> crabs = tbl(index, 1)

crabs =

   110
   140
```

Now, you can make that a one-liner:

```
>> crabs = tbl(tbl(:, 2)==1, 1)
```